Can Memory Be Contiguous With PIMPL Idiom?
Foo.h
class Foo
{
private:
    int a;
    bool b;
    float c;
};

I have a class like the one above that is used when interacting with an API that itself interacts with the GPU.
To reduce CPU->GPU transfers, this API configures buffers in GPU memory / VRAM based on contiguous segments of CPU memory / RAM. This means the buffers are populated by (in most cases) arrays of something like Foo with the API expecting a, b, c, etc. to be at exact offsets in RAM from the start of each Foo instance. Normally this isn't a problem as I can just tell the buffer to check the offsetof() each member in Foo, but the trouble comes with added context.
I am trying to integrate Foo itself into my own API and so I want to use PIMPL to hide the declaration of Foo's members from users of the API:
Foo.h
#include <memory>

class Foo
{
    class PIMPL;
public:
    Foo();
private:
    std::unique_ptr<PIMPL> impl;
};

Foo.cpp
class Foo::PIMPL{
public:
    int a;
    bool b;
    float c;
};

Foo::Foo(){
    impl = std::make_unique<PIMPL>();
}

Now the member declarations are compiled away from users of my API in the .cpp file but that now means I can no longer guarantee that a, b, c, etc. are of consistent contiguous RAM offsets from the start of each Foo instance in the aforementioned buffers since as far as I understand the call to std::make_unique<PIMPL>() could instantiate PIMPL anywhere in RAM and not necessarily right next to the instance of Foo it belongs to.
What solutions are available to me to allow PIMPL to hide member declarations from users of my API and still guarantee that each member hidden by PIMPL will be at a consistent RAM offset from the start of any & every Foo instance?

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/299834

Awesome, this seems to be exactly what I need. I'll try it out and if you don't hear anything you can assume it worked, thank you!

There's probably a dupe-target here on SO, that's just what I managed to turn up in a minute or two of Googling.

Yeah I tried to google for it but my search terms weren't specific enough, I was just looking up stuff like 'C++ rearrange memory' or 'C++ ensure contiguous memory'.

Much closer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921932/pimpl-idiom-without-using-dynamic-memory-allocation/, of note: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4921996

I think they're fundamentally incompatible. IIUC, PIMPL relies on indirection through a pointer, you can't have the data directly in the array.
